# Use firstof and striptags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

As part of a Facebook sharekit, I have this code:

```
data-share-description="{% firstof foo.bar foo.baz bang.pow bang.zap %}"
```

which returns the correct value, but includes HTML tags.  If I add a "striptags" filter after each value, it seems that firstof is recognizing "None" as a non-False value and returning that instead rather than proceeding down the list.

EDIT:

```
foo.bar = ''
foo.baz = None
bang.pow = '<i>Italicized text</i> and some more'
bang.zap = 'Something else'
```

Without striptags after each firstof variable, it returns `<i>Italicized text</i> and some more` which is not what I want, but is what I expect.  With strip tags, it prints out `None`.  If I remove `foo.baz` from the `firstof` sequence, I get the expected and desired value of `Italicized text and some more`.

EDIT AGAIN:

Because `foo.baz` is `None`, striptags is throwing a TypeError of `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`.  I think this is the problem but no idea how to fix it.

Comment: if `foo.bar` is, for example, "<i>Some Italic text</i> followed by <u>some underlined text</ul>" the out put is just "followed by".  I'd like to strip the tags.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? I can't reproduce this issue. If I put just `{% firstof None False '<strong>BOLD</strong>' %}` in a template and render it with a blank context, I get `u'<strong>BOLD</strong>\n'`. If your problem description was accurate, I would expect to get an empty string or just a newline.

Comment: 1.8.4 -- maybe I'm misidentifying the issue, then.  I mean, that's what I'd expect too, but something is definitely removing all attributed text when shared to Facebook.

Comment: I can't think of any reason to favor either approach, except that perhaps this needs a comment cleanup now. I've deleted my older comments except the one with code in case you want to use that idea for testing or incorporate it into a future edit/question.

Comment: K--I'm seeing some other weird bugs now; will investigate in the morning and come back with more info.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `striptags` seems to choke on `None` values, you *could* chain another call to default. That means you'd end up with something like this:

```
{% firstof foo.baz|default:''|striptags bar.quux|default:''|striptags %}
```

for each element in the list. I believe you'll agree this is quite cumbersome.

This is why I think it's time for you to create your own custom tag that performs this procedure for you:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def firstof_striptags(*args):
    for arg in args:
        if arg:
            return strip_tags(arg)
```

I'm not sure this fully complies with your use case and you may want to read up on some topics like [Auto-escaping Considerations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#auto-escaping-considerations). This code is untested but should give you an idea what to do.